# show the number of lesson views for learnpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, learnpress, action-hook

hello I have this code snippet in function.php that actually I used a learnpress plugin hook for it:
`learn-press/course-item-content`
also I tried this one:
`learn-press/lesson-start`
and the goal is to have the number of learnpress lesson views for each lesson for guests and not logged in users.
I have created the custom field views for lp_lesson type with Pods plugin.

```
<?PHP
// I inserted this code to show the number of views for each lesson  
//*************************************************************
add_action('learn-press/course-item-content', 'lesson_views');
function lesson_views(){
     $item = LP_Global::course_item();
     if(is_user_logged_in()){
         $user = wp_get_current_user();
         if ( !in_array( 'subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
             return;
         }
     }
         echo "<script>console.log('get_post_field".get_post_field('views',$item->get_id())."'); 
</script>";
         $tempval = 0;
     if(get_post_field('views',$item->get_id())==''||get_post_field('views',$item->get_id())==null)
     {
         $tempval = 1;
         echo "<script>console.log('tempval = 1');</script>";
     }
     else
     {
         $tempval = intval(get_post_field('views',$item->get_id()))+1;
         echo "<script>console.log('tempval = ".$tempval."');</script>";
     }
         update_post_meta($item->get_id(),'views',$tempval,get_post_field('views',$item->get_id()));
         echo "<script>console.log('get_post_field".get_post_field('views',$item->get_id())."'); 
 </script>";
 //End Of the code to show the number of views for each lesson 
 //*************************************************************    
}
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'my_update_post_meta', 10, 4 );

function my_update_post_meta($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value) 
{
    echo "<script>console.log('sth updated".$_meta_value."');</script>";
    if($meta_key =="views"){
        echo "<script>console.log('views updated".$_meta_value."');</script>";
    }
}
```

I noticed that the update for the field views happens once, but when I refresh the page, it actually happened twice. for example if now the views=1 and I go to the page, it will be views=2, but after refresh the page, I understand the last value for views was not 2, but views=3! and now it will change to views=4. I checked if in the line that `$tempval = intval(get_post_field('views',$item->get_id()))+1;` happens if I change the increasing value for example to 3, it will results that if views equals 1, and I go to the page and views updates to 4, but after that I go again to the page, the value is 7 at the start, and it will change to 10 and so on. I do not get it why this happens twice while I can not see any evidence that says this code happens twice. because the script codes that I put for check happens once, and the check in update hook proves it.

Answer (score 0):

I did not found the reason behind happening this twice, but in a tricky way I could write a code to have the number of page views of a lesson and use in in elementor plugin. here is the code:

```
add_action('learn-press/lesson-start', 'lesson_views');
 function lesson_views($item){
     //$itemc = LP_Global::course_item();
     echo "<script>console.log('get_post_field".get_post_field('views',$item- 
 >get_id())."');</script>";
     $tempdata = get_post_field('views',$item->get_id());
     $postview = intval($tempdata);
     $postviewf = floatval($tempdata);
     $newvalue = floatval(0);
     if($postviewf > 0){
         if($postviewf - $postview == 0.5){
             $newvalue = round($postviewf);
         }else{
             $newvalue = $postview+0.5;
         }
         echo "<script>console.log('newvalue".$newvalue."');</script>";
     }else{
         $newvalue = 0.5;
     }
     $postID = $item->get_id();
     update_post_meta($postID,'views',$newvalue,$tempdata);
     echo "<script>console.log('get_post_field".get_post_field('views',$item- 
  >get_id())."');</script>";

 //End Of the code to show the number of views for each lesson  
 *************************************************************  
 }
 add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'my_update_post_meta', 10, 4 );
 
     function my_update_post_meta($meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value) 
     {
         echo "<script>console.log('sth updated".$_meta_value."');</script>";
         if(get_post_type( $post_id )=='lp_lesson' && $meta_key =="views"){
             echo "<script>console.log('views updated".$_meta_value."');</script>";
             update_post_meta($post_id,'viewsv2',round($_meta_value));
         }
     }
```

if you try to view `viewsv2` as custom field in elementor plugin it shows the exact number of page views for users with role subscriber which are students and not logged in users which are guests.